# Downgrading from iOS 9 to 8.3 with 9 backup

Tags: iphone, backup, ios

So I upgraded to the iOS 9 beta and it didn't take much time for me to decide I wanted 8.3 back. Nothing was really wrong, its just that there are a lot of major and minor glitches that I just couldn't deal with. So I did everything right, got the 8.3 download and restored my iPhone 6 from there. Before doing so I did a backup on iOS 9 so I could get all my photos and other data back. As soon as I got back to 8.3 I tried restoring from backup, but itunes tells me that my software is too old and that i would have to set my phone up as a new iphone. Considering I just got a new mac yesterday. I have no previous backups besides the iOS 9 one. I know what my problem is, I didn't backup on 8.3 before upgrading. I'm just wondering if anyone has had this problem or one similar and could give me some solutions or am I just stuck with iOS 9 beta until it officially releases?

Comment: The -1 is not for the question, per se... it's for discovering the hard way that you don't put beta software on mission-critical devices.

Answer (score 1):

Restoring from backup wipes the device, installs the newest version of iOS, then restores the contents of the backup. Generally speaking the backup is version agnostic - you can restore a 7.1 backup directly onto a device running 8.3, for example. In this case the data in the backup is from a newer version (9 beta) than iTunes is installing on the device (8.3), so you can't restore that data.

Your options are sticking with 9 beta, or starting over with a new phone experience on 8.3.